# Assembly: [SI + CX] = impossible combination of address sizes

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, interrupt, cpu-registers

So, today I tried to create a library for my in-development OS with one simple function: To print characters on screen. To use this function I simply have to push the string address to the stack and call it (The string **must** end with a 0x00 byte). Below is the source code of the function:

```
__print:                        ;Print string that is terminated with a 0x00 to screen

__print_prepare:
    pop si                  ;SI Register = String Address
    mov ah, 0x0E                ;0x0E Function = Print Character on screen
    mov bx, 0x0F                ;Background = Black, CharColor = White
    xor cx, cx              ;Counter = 0

__print_check:
    push byte [cx + si]         ;Push character to the stack
    or byte [cx + si], byte [cx + si]   ;Check if the byte equals 0x00
    jz __print_exit             ;If true then exit
    jmp __print_main            ;Else print the character

__print_main:
    pop al                  ;Store the byte in the AL Register
    int 0x10                ;Call interupt 0x10 = BIOS Interupt
    jmp __print_next            ;Continue to next character

__print_next:
    inc cx                  ;Increment CX Register by one for next character = Counter
    jmp __print_check           ;Check authenticity of character

__print_exit:
    ret
```

Anytime I try to assemble the source code the following nasm error appears:

> def_os_lib.asm:10: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>
> def_os_lib.asm:11: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
>
> def_os_lib.asm:16: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Also, in some cases, that is when I compile it in ELF format, it prompts this error:

> def_os_lib.asm:10: error: impossible combination of address sizes
>
> def_os_lib.asm:11: error: impossible combination of address sizes

The command I use for nasm(bin) is:

> nasm -f bin def_os_lib.asm

The command I use for nasm(elf64) is:

> nasm -f elf64 def_os_lib.asm

I've just started assembly and I know I'm doing a too big step for my knowledge. I just want to go a little bit more in depth.

Thank you all for your help. I have completed the source code by correcting the mistakes with your suggestions. Here is the new code:

```
__print:                        ;Print string that is terminated with a 0x00 to screen

__print_prepare:
    pop si                  ;SI Register = String Address
    xor bx, bx              ;Counter = 0

__print_check:
    push bx                 ;Save BX
    xor ax, ax              ;AX = 0
    add bx, si              ;BX = Address of the character
    mov al, byte [bx]           ;AL = Character
    pop bx                  ;Restore BX
    push ax                 ;Save character
    or ax, ax               ;Check if the byte equals 0x00
    jz __print_exit             ;If true then exit
    jmp __print_main            ;Else print the character

__print_main:
    pop ax                  ;Store the byte in the AL Register
    push bx                 ;Save BX
    mov bx, 0x0F                ;Background = Black, CharColor = White
    mov ah, 0x0E                ;0x0E Function = Print Character on screen
    int 0x10                ;Call interupt 0x10 = BIOS Interupt
    jmp __print_next            ;Continue to next character

__print_next:
    pop bx                  ;Restore BX
    inc bx                  ;Increment CX Register by one for next character = Counter
    jmp __print_check           ;Check authenticity of character

__print_exit:
    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use [BX or BP] in combination with [SI or DI]; AX, DX or CX are not allowed.

You can't PUSH/POP a byte so `POP AL` so any byte-size argument will be deemed invalid.

Comment: Do you mean that the byte statement isn't needed in the push?

Comment: The byte directive specifies that the size of the argument is byte. You can't PUSH/POP a byte.

Comment: Magoo, actually you can push al, only assemblers don't let you do it. It was removed "recently" from gas and probably from nasm since that's not a good idea as you explain.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Um, no - byte push/pop is't supported by x86 architecture. Assemblers may have not objected, and implemented word instructions when a byte was specified, but that is a bug in the assembler - even if it was exploited. Now you could implement a push-byte as a macro, but it would need to be `dec sp mov [sp+1],al` or whatever or possibly `mov [sp],al dec sp` but it certainly wouldn't be efficient. I believe you'll find that what was actually implemented was `push ax` if `push al` was coded. If you have an old version, I'd be interested to see what byte code `push al` was assembled to.

Comment: It would be like this actually: `dec sp mov [sp],al` -- and you are actually correct, the minimum size you can push on the stack is a word. However, it is correct that it is not safe to use any value that is not at least 32 bit on a x86 and 64 bit on an amd64... stack alignment is generally checked these days.

Answer (score 4):

> push byte [cx + si]

[`cx` cannot be used in adressing under real mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes).

> or byte [cx + si], byte [cx + si]

You can not have two memory operands in one instruction normally in x86. You need to use a register as middleman.

Comment: So I need to mov those values to another register and then use the or on itself...

Comment: You only need to copy one of the values.