# error: invalid effective address => cmp byte [cx], 'B'

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I'm writing a boot sector code which contains the statements below:

```
xor cx, cx                      ;clear CX
cmp [cx], 'B'
```

I receive the error thrown by NASM:

> error: operation size not specified

---

I modify the code like this:

```
cmp byte [cx], 'B'
```

However I receive another error:

> error: invalid effective address

---

I'm searching on the error but I don't get to know why that is thrown

Comment: Only a limited selection of registers can be used there.

Comment: 16-bit addresses can only use limited registers.  `[BX|BP] + [DI|SI]`, omit either base or index.  Since you're zeroing `cx`, you could simply use `cmp byte [0], 'B'`

Comment: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html

Comment: @PeterCordes `cx` register would be a counter in a loop. My other registers are filled by other things right now. Well, I think I might have to modify my code a whole lot

Comment: Been searching for some nice duplicate with *"in x86-16 you have only these addressing modes available ..."*, but actually I didn't find one (only 32/64 bit ones). I give up, that external link was the best I found in one 32/64 answer. OP: also `bp, si, di` used? All of them? What are you doing? :-o :D

Comment: @user3405291: use si, di, or bx as your loop counter, then, and use cx instead of one of those.  The `loop` instruction is only useful for code-size reasons; [it's not fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently), so other than that CX is mostly only special for shift counts (in CL).

Comment: @Ped7g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786631/assembly-si-cx-impossible-combination-of-address-sizes has an answer that links the diagram on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes.

Comment: @Ped7g: Actually, another one of SO's "related" links already had an answer that lists the full table of possibilities.  I retitled it and linked wikipedia: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes